# ¿Cómo puedo desmarcar un <option> de un select múltiple cuando marque otro <option> de ese mismo select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, materialize

Estoy haciendo un formulario que posee varios `select`, unos simples y otros múltiples. Los valores que se seleccionan en esos `select` aparecen en un `span` en forma de texto.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
var ninguno = true;
function displayValores() {
  var selectValues = $("#myid").val() || [];
  var select_and_or = $("#and_or").val();

  // si Ninguno está marcado pero se marca algo diferente
  if (ninguno && (selectValues.length > 1 || selectValues[0] != "Ninguno")) {
    // desmarcar ninguno
    $("#myid option[value=Ninguno]").removeAttr("selected");
    // actualizar los nuevos valores seleccionados
    selectValues = $("#myid").val()
    // indicar que Ninguno ya no está marcado
    ninguno = false;
  // si Ninguno no está marcado y se marca
  } else if (!ninguno && selectValues.indexOf("Ninguno") > -1) {
    // dejarlo como único valor
    $("#myid").val("Ninguno");
    // actualizar los nuevos valores seleccionados
    selectValues = $("#myid").val()
    // indicar que Ninguno ya está marcado
    ninguno = true;
  }
  document.querySelector('.mostrar').innerHTML = selectValues.join(" " + select_and_or + " ");
  $('.mostrar').html(selectValues.join(" " + select_and_or + " "));
}
$("select").change(displayValores);
displayValores();
```

```css
.row {
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
  <body>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').material_select();
  });
   $('select').material_select("destroy");
</script>

<div class="row">
  <span class="mostrar"></span>
  <div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="elegir">
    <select id="and_or">
        <option selected>Y</option>
        <option>O</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="colores">
    <select id="myid" multiple="multiple">
        <option Value="Ninguno" selected>Ninguno</option>
        <option> Amarillo</option>
        <option>Azul</option>
        <option>Rojo</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que deseo es lo siguiente: Que al seleccionar cualquier opción diferente a la opción "Ninguno" esta opción se me desmarque y se marque cualquiera de las otras opciones y que aparte se muestre la selección que haga el usuario de las opciones "y"/"o" del primer select.

Es decir:

1. La opción "Ninguno" me aparecerá marcada por defecto ya que tiene el atributo `selected`. Cuando esté así se mostrará "Ninguno" en el `span` y nada más.
2. Si el usuario selecciona otra de las opciones del select, por ejemplo "Amarillo", "Azul" o "Rojo", entonces la casilla de "Ninguno" debe desmarcarse.
3. Si el usuario vuelve a seleccionar la casilla de "Ninguno" entonces las opciones que ya había seleccionado deben desmarcarse y no podrán mostrarse en el span, por supuesto la opción "Y/O" del primer select tampoco debe aparecer.

ilustrado en imagenes esto es lo que se desea lograr:

Cuando la casilla "Ninguno" este seleccionada las demás opciones deben estar sin selección.
[image: Inicialmente cuando se le da click al select, así aparecen las opciones]

Cuando el usuario seleccione uno o más colores de la lista, debería desmarcarse automáticamente la opción "Ninguno", es decir ya no puede estar seleccionada. 
[image: Al seleccionar un color debería desmarcarse la opción Ninguno]

[image: Mientras el usuario tenga colores seleccionados la casilla "Ninguno" debe mantenerse desmarcada]

Si el usuario vuelve a seleccionar la opción "Ninguno", automáticamente las opciones que estaban seleccionadas (en este caso Amarillo y Rojo) deben desmarcarse. (Debería quedar como en la primera imagen).

Ahora bien, Con la implementación del código anterior no se obtiene al 100%  el resultado deseado.

Este es el resultado de aplicar el código anterior:
esto se debe colocar al inicio del de la etiqueta body, de esta forma materialize permite que se creen los elementos "Select". Si esto no se coloca al inicio, sencillamente los selects no se muestran.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

inicialmente Ninguno esta seleccionado por defecto. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede ver en la imagen, si selecciono algún color, la casilla "Ninguno" no se desmarca.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando el selectbox se cierra, "Ninguno" no sale reflejado en la parte superior (span) pero si sale reflejado en la casilla del Select.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué podría hacer para solucionar este problema? 
El framework que estoy usando para el diseño de la web es: Materializecss. Cabe acotar que este Framework tiene un plugin para manejar los elementos Selects, cuando se crea un select, de forma oculta se añaden otros elementos con los cuales por medio de jquery se maneja al elemento select. Aqui una imagen de los elementos que se agregan cuando se crea un elemento select:

[image: Elementos que se agregan al Select] 
Creo que los elementos li juegan un papel importante en este caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que los puntos 1 ya lo tienes hecho, y para los otros dos puntos los que podrías hacer es añadir una nueva variable que lleve el control de si "Ninguno" estaba marcada de antes o no y operar en consecuencia:

- Si se selecciona un valor diferente, deseleccionar "Ninguno".
- Si se selecciona "Ninguno", deseleccionar el resto de opciones.

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo comentado:

```js
var ninguno = true;

function displayValores() {
  var selectValues = $("#myid").val() || [];
  var valorSelect1 = $("#and_or").val();

  // si Ninguno está marcado pero se marca algo diferente
  if (ninguno && (selectValues.length > 1 || selectValues[0] != "Ninguno")) {
    // desmarcar ninguno
    $("#myid option[value=Ninguno]").removeAttr("selected");
    // actualizar los nuevos valores seleccionados
    selectValues = $("#myid").val()
    // indicar que Ninguno ya no está marcado
    ninguno = false;
  // si Ninguno no está marcado y se marca
  } else if (!ninguno && selectValues.indexOf("Ninguno") > -1) {
    // dejarlo como único valor
    $("#myid").val("Ninguno");
    // actualizar los nuevos valores seleccionados
    selectValues = $("#myid").val()
    // indicar que Ninguno ya está marcado
    ninguno = true;
  }

  $('.mostrar').html(selectValues.join(" " + valorSelect1));
}

$("select").change(displayValores);
displayValores();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="elegir">
    <select id="and_or">
        <option selected>Y</option>
        <option>O</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="colores">
    <select id="myid" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="Ninguno" selected>Ninguno</option>
        <option>Amarillo</option>
        <option>Azul</option>
        <option>Rojo</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <span class="mostrar"></span>
  <div>
```

Comment: Disculpa, qué está pidiendo ? lo que entendí es que quiere desmarcar una opción al marcar otra, pero eso no se hace automático ?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Si es un select multiple, puedes tener más de una opción activa pulsando la tecla control y seleccionando varias

Comment: Interesante, no lo sabia, gracias

Comment: Sigue sin resolverse el problema, ya que al marcar otra opción igual se queda marcada la opción "Ninguno", no se desmarca como quiero. La idea es que cuando yo seleccione cualquiera de las opciones (Amarillo, Azul ó Rojo) automáticamente la opción "Ninguno" se desmarque. No se si es por el framework que estoy usando (Materializecss). He estado intentando pero nada, sigue estando marcada la opción "Ninguno".

Comment: @N.bravoA ¿Podrías poner los pasos que debo seguir para que no funcione? Estoy probando en el código que he puesto y parece hacer lo que quieres sin problemas. Quizás no esté probando bien.

Comment: Podrias incorporar en el head el link de Materializecss? Creo que asi lo podrias ver mejor. Yo tengo incluso en imagenes las pruebas que hice, pero por comentarios no las puedo poner,

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.1/css/materialize.min.css">    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

Comment: y en el body se debe inicializar el plugin para el select: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').select();
  }) con eso ya podrias ver como se comporta el select en ese framework y podrias ver como al momento de darle a otra opción como Amarillo, Azul o Rojo la casilla de "Ninguno" aun queda marcada.

Comment: @N.bravoA estoy en el móvil, cuando llegue a un ordenador lo hago. Mientras tanto, te recomiendo que leas [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y que edites el código de la pregunta para añadir las referencias (así otros usuarios también podrán ver el problema)

Comment: Ok lo hare y editare el código de la pregunta y colocare las referencias. Muchas gracias por las sugerencias.

Comment: @N.bravoA he podido reproducir el problema (realmente la selección es correcta, pero no se refleja hasta que no se cierre el select y se vuelva a abrir). Voy a ver cómo lo podría cambiar para que funcione.

Comment: Si, voy a editar mi pregunta, colocare el codigo que usted me suminitstro y colocare unas imágenes de como se comporta el select en mi computador. Asi podra ver mejor el problema

Comment: Edite la publicación, ahi se puede ver mejor el porqué no esta funcionando el codigo al 100%.

Comment: @N.bravoA Espera a que la termine para marcarla como aceptada. Aún está incompleta. Lo siento, he andado bastante liado estos días

Comment: Oooh no te disculpes, se agradece el tiempo que has dedicado a esta pregunta y los aportes que has hecho para encontrar la solución.

Comment: He encontrado la solución al problema.!!

Answer (score 0):

Saludos! Inserté dos líneas a tu código JS,

$('select').material_select('destroy');
  $('select').material_select();

Lo tomé de la documentación de http://materializecss.com/forms.html Espero que te ayude!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
var ninguno = true;
function displayValores() {
  var selectValues = $("#myid").val() || [];
  var select_and_or = $("#and_or").val();

  // si Ninguno está marcado pero se marca algo diferente
  if (ninguno && (selectValues.length > 1 || selectValues[0] != "Ninguno")) {
    // desmarcar ninguno
    $("#myid option[value=Ninguno]").removeAttr("selected");
    // actualizar los nuevos valores seleccionados
    selectValues = $("#myid").val()
    // indicar que Ninguno ya no está marcado
    ninguno = false;
  // si Ninguno no está marcado y se marca
  } else if (!ninguno && selectValues.indexOf("Ninguno") > -1) {
    // dejarlo como único valor
    $("#myid").val("Ninguno");
    // actualizar los nuevos valores seleccionados
    selectValues = $("#myid").val()
    // indicar que Ninguno ya está marcado
    ninguno = true;
  }
  $('select').material_select('destroy');
  $('select').material_select();
  document.querySelector('.mostrar').innerHTML = selectValues.join(" " + select_and_or + " ");
  $('.mostrar').html(selectValues.join(" " + select_and_or + " "));
}
$("select").change(displayValores);
displayValores();
```

```css
.row {
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
  <body>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').material_select();
  });
   $('select').material_select("destroy");
</script>

<div class="row">
  <span class="mostrar"></span>
  <div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="elegir">
    <select id="and_or">
        <option selected>Y</option>
        <option>O</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="colores">
    <select id="myid" multiple="multiple">
        <option Value="Ninguno" selected>Ninguno</option>
        <option> Amarillo</option>
        <option>Azul</option>
        <option>Rojo</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eso es correcto!! Son las dos lineas que le faltaban al codigo.